# What is the effect of returning Behaviors.same from within Behaviors.setup?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

Akka's [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Behaviors$.html) says:

> `def same[T]: Behavior[T]`
>
> Return this behavior from message processing in order to advise the system to reuse the previous behavior. This is provided in order to avoid the allocation overhead of recreating the current behavior where that is not necessary.

> `def setup[T](factory: (ActorContext[T]) => Behavior[T]): Behavior[T]`
>
> `setup` is a factory for a behavior. Creation of the behavior instance is deferred until the actor is started, as opposed to Behaviors.receive that creates the behavior instance immediately before the actor is running. The factory function pass the `ActorContext` as parameter and that can for example be used for spawning child actors.
>
> `setup` is typically used as the outer most behavior when spawning an actor, but it can also be returned as the next behavior when processing a message or signal. In that case it will be started immediately after it is returned, i.e. next message will be processed by the started behavior.

I have tried to construct an actor system with the following guardian behavior:

```java
public static Behavior<SayHello> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(ctx -> {
        System.out.println(ctx.getSelf().path() + ": returning same()");
        return Behaviors.same();
    });
}
```

I was expecting Akka to recursively apply the behavior in question. In other words, I was expecting Akka to produce this infinite output:

```
akka://helloakka/user: returning same
akka://helloakka/user: returning same
akka://helloakka/user: returning same
...
```

However, it just prints it one time.

Is this behavior expected? What is the actual meaning of the behavior I provided? Can you devise a scenario where returning `same` from within `setup` makes sense?

Edit: I did another experiment, where I return the named behavior itself instead of `same`. I expected no differences, since that `same` should just be an optimization for reusing the previous behavior rather than allocating a new one. However, to my surprise, the output is actually infinite.

```java
public static Behavior<SayHello> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(ctx -> {
        System.out.println(ctx.getSelf().path() + ": returning create()");
        return create();
    });
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Behaviors.setup` (in the recent implementations: this hasn't changed semantically since prior to 2.6) is just a factory for an `akka.actor.typed.internal.BehaviorImpl.DeferredBehavior` (since your examples are using the javadsl, I'm starting from the javadsl; the scaladsl is the same under the hood here):

```scala
// factory is the function from `javadsl.ActorContext[T]` to `Behavior[T]` passed in
BehaviorImpl.DeferredBehavior(ctx => factory.apply(ctx.asJava))
```

Where `DeferredBehavior` is (omitting things like `toString`s):

```scala
object DeferredBehavior {
  def apply[T](factory: scaladsl.ActorContext[T] => Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] =
    new DeferredBehavior[T] {
      def apply(ctx: TypedActorContext[T]): Behavior[T] = factory(ctx.asScala)
    }
}

abstract class DeferredBehavior[T] extends Behavior[T](BehaviorTags.DeferredBehavior) {
  def apply(ctx: TypedActorContext[T]): Behavior[T]
}
```

Note that the `factory` isn't called until `DeferredBehavior::apply` is called.

When you spawn an actor with that behavior (`DeferredBehavior`), a classic actor which is an instance of [`ActorAdapter`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/3efbba1dbd45adcf48eb0f5d68f5f23f551ab29e/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/internal/adapter/ActorAdapter.scala#L55) is spawned.

```scala
// _initialBehavior is the DeferredBehavior in this case, omitting `if` checks that follow from this
private var behavior: Behavior[T] = _initialBehavior
def currentBehavior: Behavior[T] = behavior

def preStart(): Unit =
  try {
    // ctx is the typed ActorContext, context is the classic ActorContext
    behavior = Behavior.validateAsInitial(Behavior.start(behavior, ctx))
    if (!Behavior.isAlive(behavior)) context.stop(self)
  } finally ctx.clearMdc()
```

`Behavior.start` is effectively, for our purposes:

```scala
if (behavior.isInstanceOf[DeferredBehavior[T]]) {
  Behavior.start(behavior.asInstanceOf[DeferredBehavior[T]].apply(ctx), ctx)
} else behavior
```

So now we call the `factory` method, which in this case ultimately returns `BehaviorImpl.SameBehavior` after executing your `println`.  This `SameBehavior` gets passed to `validateAsInitial`, which throws an `IllegalArgumentException` because `Behaviors.same` and `Behaviors.unhandled` aren't valid initial behaviors.  This exception effectively kills the actor as it's being born (grisly, I know).

When you call back into `create`, on the other hand, the `factory` will return another `DeferredBehavior` with the same `factory`, so that will get repeatedly passed to `start`; depending on whether the Scala compiler used to build Akka noticed that `Behavior.start` in this case is tail-recursive this would either result in an infinite loop or a stack overflow.

A `Behaviors.setup` which results in a `Behaviors.same` only makes sense if you want an actor to be stillborn.  The side effects in `Behaviors.setup` will still happen, but if that's all you want, why not just do them directly and save the pointless overhead?

The foregoing technically only applies to normal actors.  The guardian behavior is special, in that it [first waits for the delivery of a special message from the actor system signalling that the actor system is ready](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/3efbba1dbd45adcf48eb0f5d68f5f23f551ab29e/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/internal/adapter/GuardianStartupBehavior.scala#L30), after which it wraps the behavior in
an interceptor which tears down the actor system if the behavior is no longer alive (viz. the behavior is stopped or failed).  At no point is the behavior validated as initial, but the wrapped behavior is `start`ed as above, which runs the `Behaviors.setup` block once and forgets the `factory`.

At this point the behavior is a bare `SameBehavior` which hasn't handled a single message.  If you sent a message to the `ActorSystem` (which is an `ActorRef`), it would [be interpreted by `Behaviors.interpret`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/3efbba1dbd45adcf48eb0f5d68f5f23f551ab29e/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/Behavior.scala#L252) which would find the `SameBehavior` and throw then, which would be a crash of the user actor hierarchy, but doesn't seem to (in my experiment) stop the actor system.

Comment: Since you're using this as the actor system's guardian behavior, the path is slightly different... it goes through `GuardianStartupBehavior` which processes a single message to show that the actor system infrastructure started and then goes through the interceptor to ultimately end in a similar place.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I'm grateful to learn from you. There is no real reason I would do this in practice – I am studying Akka's design and source code for my thesis, and wanted to determine the set of valid transitions between behaviors. I too thought that the validation of the behavior should fail. However, how can produce an evidence of this? If I enable the loggers, the failure is not logged.

Comment: It's possible that the fact it's a guardian behavior (thus wrapped in an interceptor), that it doesn't get validated as an initial behavior (it processes one magic message before transitioning to the guardian behavior), in which case I suspect, it effectively becomes `Behaviors.empty`

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior. Maybe [Behaviors as finite state machines](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fsm.html) can help.

An [actor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actors.html) is similar to an instance of a class, but instead of calling its methods you can only [interact](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#interaction-patterns) with them just sending messages through the [ActorRef](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.8/akka/actor/typed/ActorRef.html). A simple example of that is

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem

// start the actor system with a behavior that ignores any message of type `String`
val actorSystem = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty[String], "empty-behavior")

// send a message of type `String` to the `actorRef`
actorSystem ! "hello"
```

Here I'm creating an actor system that only accept messages of type `String`, but as you can see in the docs of [Behaviors.empty](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Behaviors$.html#empty%5BT%5D:akka.actor.typed.Behavior%5BT%5D) it will just ignore whatever it receives

> A behavior that treats every incoming message as unhandled.

So, an actor can have a `Behavior` of type `T`, which means it will only accept messages of type `T`. Let's see an example where the actor do something.

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

case object HelloMessage

// setup the behavior
val behavior = Behaviors.setup[HelloMessage.type] { context =>
  Behaviors.receiveMessage[HelloMessage.type] {
    // the logic applied for the message received
    case HelloMessage =>
      context.log.info("hello message received")
      Behaviors.same
  }
}

// start the actor system
val actorSystem: ActorSystem[HelloMessage.type] = ActorSystem(behavior, "hello-behavior")

// send a message through the actor ref
actorSystem ! HelloMessage
actorSystem ! HelloMessage
actorSystem ! HelloMessage

// the following line will note compile due to the actor system only
// accepts messages of type `HelloMessage`
actorSystem ! "hello"
```

If we execute the above example, we will see the message `hello message received` three times because we sent the `HelloMessage` three times. Let's see another example but this time instead of using `Behaviors.same` we will return a different `Behavior`.

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

// define messages that will be accepted by our actor
sealed trait Message
case object Ping extends Message
case object Pong extends Message

val behavior = Behaviors.setup[Message] { context =>
  def pingBehavior: Behaviors.Receive[Message] =
    Behaviors.receiveMessage[Message] {
      case Ping =>
        context.log.info("Ping received. Waiting for Pong")
        pongBehavior // return different behavior
      case Pong =>
        context.log.warn("Waiting for a Pong. Don't send Ping")
        Behaviors.same // return same behavior
    }

  def pongBehavior: Behaviors.Receive[Message] =
    Behaviors.receiveMessage[Message] {
      case Ping =>
        context.log.warn("Waiting for a Pong. Don't send Ping")
        Behaviors.same // return same behavior
      case Pong =>
        context.log.info("Pong received. Waiting for Ping")
        pingBehavior // return different behavior
    }
  pingBehavior // initial behavior
}

// start the actor system with the behaviors defined
val actorSystem = ActorSystem(behavior, "ping-pong-behavior")

// send Ping and Pong messages
actorSystem ! Pong
actorSystem ! Ping
actorSystem ! Ping
actorSystem ! Pong
```

The output of executing this will be

```
WARN - Waiting for a Pong. Don't send Ping
INFO - Ping received. Waiting for Pong
WARN - Waiting for a Pong. Don't send Ping
INFO - Pong received. Waiting for Ping
```

As we already see, we can send messages to an actor. Also the actors can send messages to other actors and to themself. If an actor sends a message to itself and returns the same behavior, we will be able to have the infinite output you mentioned in your question.

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

case object HelloMessage

// setup the behavior
val behavior = Behaviors.setup[HelloMessage.type] { context =>
  Behaviors.receiveMessage[HelloMessage.type] {
    case HelloMessage =>
      context.log.info("hello message received")
      context.self ! HelloMessage // send a message to itself
      Behaviors.same // return the same behavior
  }
}

val actorSystem: ActorSystem[HelloMessage.type] = ActorSystem(behavior, "infinite-behavior")

actorSystem ! HelloMessage
```

Once this code is executed, it will start printing `hello message received` for ever until you manually stop the process.

Comment: I have not asked how actors work. As the documentation I attached explains, Behaviors.setup is applied immediately without waiting for a new message: that's why I think my code should recurse. You have tried to obtain the same output by changing the code, but that's not my question and you are not addressing my concerns.